# Reading login credentials from .txt

Tags: c#

Creating a windows form application that accepts a username and password for either a lecturer or student.

After a thorough head bashing against a wall and much blood spilt, I decided to appeal to a higher power. You peeps!

Text File reads as such

---

```
Lecturer Username: nashy

Lecturer Password: studentsaremorons

Student Username: student   

Student Password: imamoron
```

---

how can I code it to differentiate between the lecturer and student users?

Here is what I have:

```
using (StreamReader login = new StreamReader("Login.txt"))
{

                if (txtUserName.Text == lecUserName && txtPassword.Text == lecPassword)
                {
                    Lecturer lec = new Lecturer();
                    lec.Show();

                }
                else if (txtUserName.Text == studUserName && txtPassword.Text == studPassword)
                {
                    Student st = new Student();
                    st.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Inccorect User Name or Password, please enter the correct credentials");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You aren't reading the contents of your reader.

Comment: What exactly does your code _not_ do at the moment that you need? Assuming lecUserName, lecPassword, studUserName and studPassword are assigned correctly from the text file, your code should differentiate between them fine.

Comment: I posted my code from ground zero, I tried string lines = login.ReadToEnd(); then using a .split to seperate after the ":" but it only registers for the first user and not the second everytime. Admittedly my question could have been written slight more comprehensively

Comment: You have to show us the code you are using to parse that file.  Obviously, in the long run, you would never put user names and passwords in an accessible file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure want you really want. But I suppose the following code will help

```
Student student = new Student();
Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer();
string line = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader login = new StreamReader("login.txt"))
    {

       while ((line = login.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          if (line.StartsWith("Lecturer Username:"))
             {
               lecturer.Username = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
             }
          else if (line.StartsWith("Lecturer Password:"))
             {
                    lecturer.Password = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
             }
          else if (line.StartsWith("Student Username:"))
             {
                  student.Username = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
             }
          else if (line.StartsWith("Student Password:"))
             {
                student.Password = line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
             }

         }
       }

     if (txtUserName.Text == lecturer.Username&& txtPassword.Text == lecturer.Password)
        {
               lecturer.Show();
        }
     else if (txtUserName.Text == student.Username && txtPassword.Text == student.Username)
        {
                student.Show();
        }
     else
       {
                MessageBox.Show("Inccorect User Name or Password, please enter the correct credentials");
        }
```

Comment: This was very helpful, you deserve at least 12 cookies. Sorry I was a tad vague in my description, was very early in the morning and I was at my wits end.